# replacing specific html tag within markup using replace

Tags: javascript, html

I have a block of markup that was returned in my console. I simply want to use .replace to change a tag or remove a tag. When I try using .replace--It says not a function, but when I change it to .html().replace("

","") nothing happens. Any help?

```js
//.html().replace("<p></p>,"");
```

```html
"<div class=\"files\" data-scope=\"topicContent\"></div><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"topicContent$id\" id=\"topicContent$id\" value=\"topicContent\">\n\t\t\t\t\t<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"more\" id=\"\" value=\"11961\">\n\t\t\t\t\t<input type=\"hidden\" class=\"editor\" name=\"topicContent$html\" id=\"topicContent$html\" value=\"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html><head>\n\n</head>\n<body style=&quot;font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;color: #494c4e;&quot;>\n<html><head></head><body><p><iframe src=&quot;/d2l/lp/&quot; height=&quot;200px&quot; width=&quot;600px&quot;></iframe></p>\n<p>Hello John Okay!iss tgjgjjk blhk fsf daught duck stewn sabjkbb bnsadn nnotnnnn bj</p>\n<p>\n<script src=&quot;/shared/js/epy.js&quot;></script>\n</p></body></html>\n</body></html>\">"
```

Comment: A typo in "replace" - .replace("<p></p>", "")

Comment: even with that--still doesn't replace or remove the <p> in the string

Comment: Because your line doesn't have a <p></p>

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 const  htmlStr = '<div class=\\"files\\" data-scope=\\"topicContent\\"></div><input type=\\"hidden\\" name=\\"topicContent$id\\" id=\\"topicContent$id\\" value=\\"topicContent\\">\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t<input type=\\"hidden\\" name=\\"more\\" id=\\"\\" value=\\"11961\\">\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t<input type=\\"hidden\\" class=\\"editor\\" name=\\"topicContent$html\\" id=\\"topicContent$html\\" value=\\"<!DOCTYPE html>\\n<html><head>\\n\\n</head>\\n<body style=&quot;font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;color: #494c4e;&quot;>\\n<html><head></head><body><p><iframe src=&quot;/d2l/lp/&quot; height=&quot;200px&quot; width=&quot;600px&quot;></iframe></p>\\n<p>Hello John Okay!iss tgjgjjk blhk fsf daught duck stewn sabjkbb bnsadn nnotnnnn bj</p>\\n<p>\\n<script src=&quot;/shared/js/epy.js&quot;></script>\\n</p></body></html>\\n</body></html>\\">'
```

then :

```
  htmlStr.replace("<p>", "")
  htmlStr.replace("</p>", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered such problem , before, but it was just that I was trying to access it in the wrong way, just check very well, You may probably trying to access the function in the wrong.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Some user defined functions can override built in fiction; outside that it can be a case sensitive issue that is matching upper case letter to lower case letter; cross check your code very well.